# Docker connecting to docker mysql (jdbc url)

Tags: mysql, docker, jdbc

I've a running MySQL database on a container that looks like this (docker-compose):

```
version: '3'

services:

  my-database:
    image: mysql:latest
    volumes:
      - ./data:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    container_name: db
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: admin
      MYSQL_DATABASE: MYDATABASE
    cap_add:
      - SYS_NICE
    ports:
      - "3308:3306"
    networks:
      - database

networks:
  database:
    external: true
```

When I'm running my app, I use the following jdbc url : jdbc:mysql://localhost:3308/DATABASE-NAME and it works pretty well.

Now I've "dockerized" my app, but when running the app as a container (connected to the same network) with the same jdbc url, the dockerized app cannot connect to the database. I can't figure out why.

Here is the docker-compose :

```
version: "3.8"

networks:
    database:
        external: true

services: 
    my-api:
        image: my-api:latest
        container_name: my-api
        ports:
            - "127.0.100.1:8080:8080"
        networks:
            - database
```

But it fails to connect to the database.

Exception is :

```
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method)

at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:589)

at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:542)

at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:597)

at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:333)

at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:648)

at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:156)

at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:63)
```

Comment: have you mixed up `MYSQL_DATABASE` and `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD`? What's the exact error? As a containerized app wouldn't this be using 3306 as its on the same internal network.

Comment: I've updated the post, this is indeed an error in the post not the configuration. For the exception, I've added it as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that your database network is a bridge network. In that case, containers on the network can address each other using their service names and the ports the container exposes.

In your case, your connection string should be `jdbc:mysql://db:3306/DATABASE-NAME`

`db` is the name you've given the database container and 3306 is the port the container exposes.

If you don't need to access the database directly from the host, you can remove the mapping of the port in your docker-compose file.

Comment: Thanks, as @danblack also suggested, it is indeed the port that was the issue ! 

Now, I need to find a way to have a common db.config file and a common docker-compose for both running locally and from the container

Comment: per docs - [volume mount /etc/mysql/conf.d - (under "Using a custom MySQL configuration file")](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql), and locally you can `!includedir the same directory.